# Norm of the linear functional $l(f)=\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin^{2}(x)dx$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space $C[0,\pi]$ with supremum norm.The norm of the linear functional $$l(f)=\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin^{2}(x)dx$$ is

$A.$ $1.$

$B.$ $\frac{\pi}{2}$

$C.$ $\pi$

$D.$ $2\pi$

According to me answer is $C$ as explained below

$\|l(f)\|=\|\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\sin^{2}(x)dx\|\leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\|f(x)\||\sin^{2}x|dx\leq\int_{0}^{\pi}\|f\|dx\leq \pi\|f\|$

Please check my solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know that the norm is achieved?

Comment: If i was so sure then why i asked the question...

Comment: You say that 'C' is answer. For that you need to show that the norm is achieved.

Comment: $\|f\|$=Inf$\{k:\|f(x)\|\leq k\|x\|\}$

Comment: This just gives you that $\|f\| \le \pi$

Comment: Yes you are right....can you solve it further more...

Comment: Why don't you look at $I(1)$?

Comment: $\pi/2?$........

Comment: If you think about it, $l(1)$ really ought to be the maximum on the unit ball, as this functional is monotone.

Comment: Yes it will be $\pi/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $f$ with $\|f\| \le 1$, we have $$0 \le l(1-f)=l(1)-l(f)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_o^\pi f(x)\sin^2x dx$$ which gives that $$\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\sin^2x dx \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Similarly, $$0 \le l(1+f)=l(1)+l(f)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_o^\pi f(x)\sin^2x dx$$ which gives that $$-\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\sin^2x dx \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

These two together imply that $|l(f)| \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $\|f\| \le 1$. With $l(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, it is evident that $\|l\|=\frac{\pi}{2}$.